# Replace name of XML tags in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, xml

I need to rename all tags from an xml file by nodejs. I thought about making use of regex, using the fs to read the file, but i was kind of lost.

```
<RESULTS>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="DATA_CRIACAO"><![CDATA[24/08/18]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="PLACA"><![CDATA[AAA123]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="CHASSI"><![CDATA[YYYYY]]></COLUMN>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="DATA_CRIACAO"><![CDATA[23/08/18]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="PLACA"><![CDATA[BBB123]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="CHASSI"><![CDATA[XXXXX]]></COLUMN>
    </ROW>
</RESULTS>
```

For example, replace:

```
<COLUMN NAME="DATA_CRIACAO"><![CDATA[24/08/18]]></COLUMN>
<COLUMN NAME="PLACA"><![CDATA[AAA123]]></COLUMN>
<COLUMN NAME="CHASSI"><![CDATA[YYYYY]]></COLUMN>
```

to:

```
<DATA_CRIACA><![CDATA[24/08/18]]></DATA_CRIACA>
<PLACA><![CDATA[AAA123]]></PLACA>
<CHASSI><![CDATA[YYYYY]]></CHASSI>
```

Comment: You should clearly use an XML parser for this, regex is not the right Tool.

Comment: I tried to use xml2js but the conversion to json gets so confuse because these tags ..

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you insist on using regex, this will do:

```
/<COLUMN NAME=\"([^\"]*)\"><([^>]*)></COLUMN>/gi
```

This will match the content of `'COLUMN'` line, making two capturing groups, that is used for replacement.

1st Group: content inside quotes.

2nd Group: The CDATA content.

This is going to be replaced by:

```
<$1><$2><$1>
```

That will be the captured groups surronded by '`<>`'.

How to use:

```
var testStr = "<RESULTS>\n"
    + "<ROW>\n"
    + "<COLUMN NAME="DATA_CRIACAO"><![CDATA[24/08/18]]></COLUMN>\n"
    + "<COLUMN NAME="PLACA"><![CDATA[AAA123]]></COLUMN>\n"
    + "<COLUMN NAME="CHASSI"><![CDATA[YYYYY]]></COLUMN>\n"
    + "</ROW>\n"
    + "<ROW>\n"
    + "<COLUMN NAME="DATA_CRIACAO"><![CDATA[23/08/18]]></COLUMN>\n"
    + "<COLUMN NAME="PLACA"><![CDATA[BBB123]]></COLUMN>\n"
    + "<COLUMN NAME="CHASSI"><![CDATA[XXXXX]]></COLUMN>\n"
    + "</ROW>\n"
    + "</RESULTS>\n";

var regex = /<COLUMN NAME=\"([^\"]*)\"><([^>]*)></COLUMN>/gi;

var result = testStr.replace(regex, '<$1><$2></$1>');
```

Now result will be equal to your desired output.